# Unable to Copy Rendered HTML Signature Into Gmail

Tags: html, email, gmail

After a fair bit of looking around, the only way I've found to get a signature on gmail is to copy the rendered HTML signature. Two problems arose: 1) I couldn't actually select my entire signature, and I can't even see what I am selecting like how it works with regular text and other's tutorials for gmail signatures. 2) If I press Ctrl+A on Firefox (Chrome only copies half, even when I use Ctrl+A), I can manage to copy my signature, but if I try to paste in the signature box, it glitches out and appears static in the top left of that specific Chrome/Firefox tab, like this (edited for privacy reasons):

[image]

And if I try to just go for it and email (after saving changes), no signature will be rendered at all. Not too sure what to do at this point, so any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

EDIT: [This is the HTML I use to render the signature.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c317256eb63f0811231ff3804e216fb) As a side note, I do replace those placeholder file names with links from an image hosting site. I also add 3  tags around a few of the ""s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I found the solution after playing with various HTML and image options. The problem lies in my use of the `<div>` tag for the layout of the signature. I should have been using `<td>`. Using the slice tool in Illustrator will render the HTML with `<div>` tags, while using ruler guides in Photoshop and saving for web (I used the legacy option) will render with `<td>` tags. I'm going to do a little more digging and see if using guides in Illustrator will still render with `<div>` tags, but I'm not sure if this site is the place to discuss this piece of the problem.

EDIT: By the way, Illustrator just really likes `<div>`s, so if anyone is looking to do this same thing, use Photoshop's legacy Save for Web mode. It will generate the `<td>` tags for you.

Comment: anything to do with emails has to be tables so you are sure it will work. With tables you can use valign, align and others to make the contents of a td stick to where you want them placed.